# git branch --contains errors "no such commit", while github shows that commit exists

Tags: git, github

I want to check what branches contains this github [commit](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/5ff786ae103161465d84ecdfdc5b0cfd8839eac8).
So i performed following terminal spells on one of my boxes running git version `1.9.5.msysgit.1`:

```
git clone git@github.com:npm/npm.git && cd npm
git branch -a --contains 5ff786ae103161465d84ecdfdc5b0cfd8839eac8
```

Surprisingly, I'm getting error that such commit does not exist at all:

```
error: no such commit 5ff786ae103161465d84ecdfdc5b0cfd8839eac8
```

> How this can happen if github shows this commit?

Comment: Do you have the commit localy? Maybe a missing pull?

Comment: @ckruczek If I understand `git` correctly, `clone` operation retrieves all commits. How it's possible if i `clone` a latest version from github, but commit is missing? O_O

Comment: My questions aimed exactly for the opposite. I thought you might didn't pulled the latest version. So if I understand you correctly you cloned and this is the latest version. Than its a bit weired. Could you try a `git log | grep 'thecomitid'` and see the output. If the log also does not contain the commit, then you really don't have the latest version.

Comment: @ckruczek The log also does not contains a commit :(.

Comment: Then you have a more serious problem as expected. You might need to pull again to be really sure you pulled and merged ALL branches properly

Comment: @ckruczek Does that mean `clone` is not enough? :(

Comment: No thats not what I mean. But when did you cloned and when did you pulled the last time? Or did you just cloned right now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79641/discussion-between-ckruczek-and-eye-of-hell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we figured out this is due to the fact that github shows you in a weired way an orphaned commit. Actually they performed some history rewriting and the commit got kicked out of the official history. But it is still reachable, if you perform a

```
$ git log --all -grep="Sort actions by dependency order"
```

you still find the correct commit.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on a linux server.

fixed it by `git fetch`